# How to get a value from a JObject using a partial match on the property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a `JObject` (Newtonsoft.json) and I'm extracting some values from it.
I'm using the `GetValue` function for example:

```
item.GetValue("text.English.Status")
```

but I don't know which language it will be.

So I would like to do something like a regex's match:
`text.*.Status`

How can I accomplish this?

I tried something like this:

```
item.First<JToken>(p => p.ToString().Contains("Status"))
```

And indeed it gives me the current token, but I can't find a way to extract the value without knowing its exact location.

Example json:

```
{
  "string.Language": "Turkish",
  "text.English.FullName": "Aşk-ı Beşiktaş ❤",
  "text.English.ScreenName": "kardelensimsek9",
  "text.English.Status": "19.03 KARA TOPRAĞA BEYAZ KEFENLE GÖMÜLÜRKEN BAŞ UCUMUZA KONCAK SİYAH BEYAZ ATKININ HAYALİYLE YAŞIYORUZ. VAR MI ÖTESİ? ⬛⬜❤"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post an example of your json?

Comment: thanks added in the above post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.  What you need to do is find the `JProperty` in the `JObject` whose `Name` contains your target string, then get the value from that property.

Here is an example:

```
string json = @"
{
  ""string.Language"": ""Turkish"",
  ""text.English.FullName"": ""Aşk-ı Beşiktaş ❤"",
  ""text.English.ScreenName"": ""kardelensimsek9"",
  ""text.English.Status"": ""19.03 KARA TOPRAĞA BEYAZ KEFENLE GÖMÜLÜRKEN BAŞ UCUMUZA KONCAK SİYAH BEYAZ ATKININ HAYALİYLE YAŞIYORUZ. VAR MI ÖTESİ? ⬛⬜❤""
}";

JObject item = JObject.Parse(json);

JProperty prop = item.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains(".Status"));
string value = prop != null ? prop.Value.ToString() : "(value not found)";

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/okGdx9

If you want to use Regex, you can replace `p.Name.Contains(".Status")` with `Regex.IsMatch(p.Name, @"text\..*\.Status")` in the above code.

Comment: thanks for answering.
Won't it work both for the key AND value in the JSON?

So if some of my "values" contains .Status, the prop might return them?

I mean something like:

{ "string.English.FullName" : "Brian .Status Rogers" }

Comment: No, the code in my answer above only looks at the property Name.  You can edit the code in the Fiddle and see for yourself.